# Detecting multiple patterns using grepl with large pattern vectors in R

Tags: regex, r, string, string-matching, grepl

catalog is a character vector with different values. It has the following structure

```
value   name    location    companybrand        
1111    ikea    boston      nike
1234    7/11    new york    marlboro
1456    walmart new york    marlboro
```

listing contains all the cities in United States -> Chicago, Boston, New York, Los Angeles and another column with the full name of the brands

```
Location                    Brand
New York, 5th Avenue        Coca Cola LTD
New York, 51 Str            Nike Corporation 
New York, Broadway          Marlboro Incorporated

if (sum(grepl(paste("\\b", as.character(location), "\\b", sep = ""), catalog$value[i], fixed = FALSE)) > 0 && 
    sum(grepl(paste("\\b", as.character(companybrand), "\\b", sep = ""), catalog$value[i], fixed = FALSE)) > 0){
  subdata <- subset(listing, listing$local == as.character(location[which(grepl(paste("\\b", as.character(location), "\\b", sep = ""), catalog$value[i], fixed = FALSE)]) && listing$commercial == as.character(companybrand[which(grepl(paste("\\b", as.character(companybrand), "\\b", sep = ""), catalog$value[i], fixed = FALSE))]))
}
```

As you can see, I am attempting to run a grepl function using multiple patterns which returns the following error:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(paste("\\b", distmunicipality, "\\b", sep = ""), ctlg$distvalor[i],  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have read in other posts that the appropriate solution to this is to collapse all the patterns to be tested into a single string with pipe separators, as follows:

```
companybrand <- paste(companybrand, collapse = "|")
location <- paste(location, collapse = "|")
```

which works fine for small vectors, but in my case I have 4 million elements in companybrand, which causes my R to terminate because of insufficient memory. Is there a practical way of doing this (perhaps using sapply) to run this match without it being to computationally taxing?

Comment: Look at the `stringi` package. It's C/++-backed and most operations are vectorized over `string` and `pattern` (that use `string` and `pattern`). It will probably be both significantly faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I did use the stringr package earlier, sepcifically the str_detect function to excute this, and though it works, it seemed to me that with a massive volume of data it was quite inefficient, which is why I resorted to using grepl under the assumption that R base functions are more computationally efficient. Am I wrong in thinking so?

Comment: @AvinashRaj My output would be a subset of the data frame "listing". For the given catalog value at iteration i, it should find which "location" and "companybrand" are in that string and subset the data frame "listing" accordingly. As you can tell this is part of a larger code, hence the i indexing.

Comment: `stringi` (the underpinnings of `stringr`) will be far more efficient than base (and also handle a wider array of character data, not that you may need that now). it's based on http://site.icu-project.org/. You can `mclapply` this too if you're not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this question still lives.

It seems as though the problem is you have two names for each brand and location you want to merge the two datasets on brand and location so that you can have at your fingertips the information from both sources of data.  Sounds like a [fuzzy merge or approximate match merge](http://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-data-sets-based-on-partially-matched-data-elements/).

Anyhow, trying to answer the OP, its not so much about how to create a giant logic gate, but more about how to apply a bunch of smaller logic gates.

In your example, you mention the problem with a concatenated pipe list is that it would be 4 million entries long.  I'd suggest something like the following:

```
require(data.table)
catalog<- data.table(value=c("1111","1234","1456"),
                     name=c("ikea","7/11","walmart"),
                     location=c("boston","new york","new york"),
                     companybrand=c("nike","marlboro","marlboro"))

listing<-data.table(Location=c("New York, 5th Avenue","New York,51 str","New York, Broadway"),
                    Brand=c("Coca Cola LTD","Nike Corporation","Marlboro Incorporated"))


for(companybrand in unique(catalog$companybrand)){
  listing[grepl(paste0("\\b",companybrand,"\\b"),Brand,ignore.case=TRUE),
          companybrand:=companybrand]
}

for(location in catalog$location){
 listing[grepl(paste0("\\b",location,"\\b"),location,Location,ignore.case=TRUE),
    location:=location]
}

dictionary<-listing[complete.cases(listing)]
```

Note: if the brands and locations in `catalog` are far more numerous than in`listing`, then I'd invert the code and make the for loop go over the smaller `listing` entries.

The code above generates a dictionary that you can use to look up Location-Brand pairs (or location-companybrand pairs) for their translations, and it should be more memory efficient (I have not tested this).

To subset the data at this point, all you need to do is merge the dictionary (possibly renaming the  dictionary columns) with whichever dataset you want to subset by the column names that dataset uses.